# Time of delaying prayer

Tags: prayer-timings

•Assalamu'Alaykuk O-Rahmatullah O-Barokatuh!
Hi!  haw are you brothers and sisters? 
When you pray Farj prayer after sun rise is that going to be delaying prayer? 
JazakAllahkhoir. 
•Os-salamu'Alaykum O-Rahmatullah O-Barokatuh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wa Alaikum As Salam Wa Rahmatullah Wa Barakatuh, dear brother :) Alhamdulillah by the Mercy of Allah (ﷻ), I am doing well. I hope you are in the best of health as well.

Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) said, "the time of the morning prayer is from the appearance of dawn, as long as the sun has not risen" ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/222)). This defines the time period in which prayer may be offered. After sunrise, the prayer would be considered late. It is haram to intentionally delay it to the point of being late. Make sure to offer Fajr before the sun starts to rise.

Comment: JazakAllahJoir! So that means if I pray Farj before the adhan of Duhur is going to be delaying Salah right?

Comment: Yes, that would be delayed.